# Visual Studio 2012, Monogame C# Project not able to load content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xna, monogame

I've loaded the content (LKhead.xnb) into my project after building it in XNA, but I get this error when I try to build

{Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: Could not load Content/LKhead asset as a non-content file! ---> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException: The directory was not found. --->

Comment: Check your Content folder. Ususally it's `TargerPath/Content`, but you may not have that folder there. Either create it, or change the content folder to some other path.

Comment: Are you using XNA or MonoGame here? The error implies that the file is not being copied to the output directory on build. Check that the file is indeed there and check that the content files are market as Content in the properties window.

Answer (score 2):

Content is compiled from your source format *to* xnb. You should just need to put your source content in the Content project, then you can load them by name only (no extension) by using:

```
Content.Load<type>("LKhead");
```

If LKhead is an image, add `LKhead.png` to the Content project, then in the game, when you load, do:

```
Texture2D myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("LKhead");
```

Don't touch the xnb files since they are compiled. If you want to move them around, do it in the Content project then compile.

Comment: While this works for XNA, it doesn't work for Monogame. Monogame, at the moment, doesn't support content projects.